# Как правильно использовать PUT запросы?

Tags: http, api, rest, любой-язык, put

У меня есть метод контроллера (псевдокод):

```
HttpResult put(putViewModel){...}
```

Объект `putViewModel` имеет поля `Id`, `ClientName`, `Email` и еще тысяча различных полей. Все поля являются обязательными.

Если я хочу сменить, например, только имя клиента, не трогая `Email`, мне стоит позволить отправлять на метод данные вроде таких:

```
{
  "id":123,
  "ClientName": "New name"
}
```

Или требовать отправлять все обязательные данные, чтобы было так:

```
{
  "id":123,
  "ClientName": "New name",
  "Email" : "oldemail@domain.com
   ...
   -остальные поля-
   ...
}
```

PUT ведь должен создать запись, если ее нет, но не получив все данные я не смогу создать запись. Как правильно делать?